# CustomPresenter errors on migration from 4.4 to 5.7 in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Hello stackoverflowers, 
I am working on a project that is built using MVVMCross and Xamarin for iOS and Android. I have found out that the project uses a quite old version of MVVMCross (4.4.0) and I am trying to bring it up to the current one (6.4). I thought it's a good idea to first upgrade to 5.7 and on a later stage, when I have the navigation switched to the new form etc, I will bump up to 6++. I have sucessfully run the android version to 5.7, however, the iOS version uses a customPresenter, that I don't quite know how to transform to the new Presenter introduced in 5.1. I think my custom presenter is based on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus/XPlatformMenusTabs.iOS which hasn't been updated in a while.

In my  MvxTabPresenter that subclasses  MvxIosViewPresenter, the show function is no longer overridable. In addition IMvxModalIosView doesnt seem to exist anymore.

```
public override void Show(IMvxIosView view)
        {
            if (view is IMvxModalIosView)
            {
                if (this._currentModalViewController != null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var currentModalViewController = view as MvxViewController;
                this._currentModalViewController = currentModalViewController;
                currentModalViewController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;
                CurrentTopViewController.AddChildViewController(currentModalViewController);
                currentModalViewController.View.Frame = CurrentTopViewController.View.Bounds.Inset(10, 10);
                currentModalViewController.View.Alpha = 0;
                CurrentTopViewController.View.Add(currentModalViewController.View);
                currentModalViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(CurrentTopViewController);

                UIView.Animate(0.25, () =>
                {
                    currentModalViewController.View.Alpha = 1;
                });


                //this.PresentModalViewController(currentModalViewController, true);
                return;
            }

            if (view is HomeView)
            {
                if (this.CurrentTopViewController is MvxTabBarViewController)
                {
                    TabBarPresenter.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    return;
                } 


 public override void CloseModalViewController()
        {
            if (this._currentModalViewController != null)
            {
                this._currentModalViewController.DismissModalViewController(true);
                _currentModalViewController.WillMoveToParentViewController(null);
                _currentModalViewController.View.RemoveFromSuperview();
                _currentModalViewController.RemoveFromParentViewController();
                this._currentModalViewController = null;
                return;
            }

            base.CloseModalViewController();
        }

            }
```

Also this is no longer overridable from the superclass.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Kind regards,
V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may see in the [MvxIosViewPresenter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Ios/Presenters/MvxIosViewPresenter.cs#L88) now the mvx attributes are registered with the action that should be called.

So, firstly you should inherit from `MvxIosViewPresenter`. Then, for modal you should override `ShowModalViewController`.

I suggest you to read the [docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/ios/ios-view-presenter?scroll=800), the [MvxIosViewPresenter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Ios/Presenters/MvxIosViewPresenter.cs#L88) and [MvxAttributeViewPresenter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/a51c7648f10a79d9fabee25ff34711b1440fefd2/MvvmCross/Presenters/MvxAttributeViewPresenter.cs)  files on the repo to check out how it works.

HIH